# RamFS over sshFS as swapspace

Tags: networking, swap, sshfs

Guys I have to computers at office,

boxA - 256mb RD-ram with decent cpu

boxB - 1.5 gigs of ram with terrible cpu

Network cards are 10/100

I plan to sshfs into boxB and mount a ramfs of boxB as swapspace for boxA.
{I cannot help but be amazed by the power of default linux tools!}

Do you think, this will worth it? Any ideas to make it work better? Any way to adding

Comment: And what happens when the SSH client is swapped out?

Comment: Even if it would be stable enough, latency and throughput will probably be worse than a disk swap space.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit user-space oriented for swap space. You could look at network block devices instead, but its hard to believe you can't just get a bit more RAM for box A.